# Does anyone know what this is?

Tags: dogs, skin-condition

My female dog has a small lump on her inner thigh and I don't know what it is. She responds with yelping and squirming when I touch it, and it has recently developed a black tip on it. It is slightly squishy, but mostly hard. It's not a nipple because her other ones are dark brown.

[image: this is a picture of the bump]

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! If you are in sudden worry about the health of your pet, please do not wait for the answers of strangers from the internet. Instead see a vet, or call and ask if you can send the picture to them.

Comment: While I am not saying that this is or is not a nipple, it's worth noting that nipples aren't always the same color (even on the same dog). The pigment can be dark or light, just like  belly freckles or different fur colors.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately it's impossible for us to tell what this is without physical access to the dog. The only one who could tell for sure is a local vet.

The possibilities range from a benign skin tag over an infection to skin cancer.

There's a similar question over at [PetCoach](https://www.petcoach.co/question/?id=46489) and the answer includes:

> Be sure to visit your local Veterinarian as soon as possible and request a Fine Needle Aspiration. This will allow your doctor to rule out the presence of any infection or cancerous cells.